# Can I call an external process in a Java Web Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, tomcat

I have a program in which when a servlet is called, it executes a Matlab script file and gets the output from it. This is done using Inter-Process Communication. Following is my code snippet:

```
public synchronized String sendInput(String values) throws IOException {

    String result = "";
    String input = "''"+values+"''";
    String directory = new String("F:\\Users\\Faaadf\\Desktop\\RSPro\\");
    String matlabFile = directory + "serverfunction";
    String outputFilePath = directory+"goodfilm.txt";

    ProcessBuilder   ps=new ProcessBuilder("matlab",
                                            "-nodisplay",
                                            "-nodesktop", 
                                            "-nosplash" , 
                                            "-wait" ,
                                            "-r" , 
            "\"run('"+matlabFile+"("+input+")"+"')\";exit;");   

    ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process pr = ps.start();  
    File fi = new File(outputFilePath);

    synchronized(this){

        while(!fi.exists());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fi);
        result = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        fi.delete();

    }
    pr.destroy();
    return result;
}
```

This code works flawlessly when run from Eclipse Java EE. But, when I deploy it to Apache Tomcat 7.0, it doesn't even start the MATLAB program. My MATLAB and MATLAB script are even set in environment variables and also the script is in MATLAB path. I tried every possible way I could. Do you guys have a fix so I can deploy this webapp on Apache Tomcat server? Or any other server that would let me use interprocess communcation? Thank you!

Comment: It could be a security issue. Are you running the tomcat instance with the same user / rights on your machine? Does any exception appear?

Comment: @meistermeier Yes, the user/rights are correct. No exceptions. It basically doesnt execute the command at all! I even tried running only a Matlab instance and not the script. It doesn't work when deployed. Works in Eclipse though.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this issue? I'm facing the exact same problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @musical_coder I actually posted an answer to my own question but some ego-filled moderator removed it. Basically, I couldn't get it to work on Apache Tomcat, so I kept developing the application until it was done. Then, I just switched to JBoss instead. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Sounds good- I'll give JBoss a try. Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to connect MATLAB with Java, it is now possible:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25249-tcp-ip-socket-communications-in-matlab-using-java-classes