# Execute command prompt commands in java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I want to write a Java program , in which that need to execute a batch file to convert mp3 to wav file,am having command and its working fine in a command prompt,so to convert the file from wave to mp3 the first step is to have to change the directory to the where that batch file presents and then i need to execute `mu-law-mp3.bat muic` command in command prompt now my question is how i can achieve this through Java?

In my java program

1. I need to execute cd command to the location of batch file
2. I need to execute above command .

Comment: Take the time to do some research into `ProcessBuilder`.  If you have problems with that, then feel free to post what you have tried and I'm sure we'll be able to help then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.You can also specify the location of the file in the command itself.

```
  ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(command);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process=pb.start();
    BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

    while(inStreamReader.readLine() != null){
        //do something with commandline output.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use of java.lang.Process.

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, null,workingDirFile);

commands is String[] containing command and arguments required in string format
envP is second variable, set it to null
workingDirFile is object of File object of working directory

Thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score -1):

Check this post out. I created a program in Java that called MATLAB that you can see there.

[Can I call an external process in a Java Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954463/can-i-call-an-external-process-in-a-java-web-application/23054479#23054479)

You use ProcessBuilder to do so!